# Is this constexpr integer not a null pointer constant?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

Consider the following C++11 program, and its result in GCC 4.7.2:

```
int main()
{
   constexpr int i = 0;
   int* p = i;
}

// g++ -g -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++11 t.cpp
// t.cpp: In function 'int main()':
// t.cpp:4:13: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]
// t.cpp:4:9: warning: unused variable 'p' [-Wunused-variable]
```

According to the standard:

> `[C++11: 4.10/1]:` A *null pointer constant* is an integral constant expression (5.19) prvalue of integer type that evaluates to zero [..]

5.19 is a mess and I've failed to parse it fully, but wouldn't we expect `i` to satisfy this criterion and act as a *null pointer constant*, consequently requiring no explicit conversion to `int*` for the initialisation of `p`?

The compilation succeeds if I `s/constexpr/const/` and compile with `-ansi` rather than `-std=c++11`.

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to be a null pointer constant, mainly because `i` is a lvalue. However, since the expression somewhat involves lvalue-to-rvalue conversions and after that, the standard makes a constant expression, we can reasonably argue it is a NPC however perverse that might be. Note that it causes chaos in overload resolution, esp. when you're using unknown values eg. in templates. BTW I wouldn't take gcc as an benchmark here, their handling of constants is horrible.

Comment: If the language were redesigned from scratch today than `nullptr` would be required everywhere and you would never be able to assign an integral type (constant or otherwise) to a pointer without a cast.  I think it makes sense to limit it only to a literal `0` for backwards compatibility, there is no use for using a more complicated constant expression that happens to evaluate to zero as a null pointer constant.

Comment: Please note Lippman's C++ primer, 5th edition (covering c++11) Exercise 2.32 which is pretty much the same thing.  I'm thinking that the OP has the correct answer, and gcc is what's giving the issue here.  Any comments?

Comment: @FlipMcF: At time of writing, the committee has this issue as "pending review" still.

Comment: Came here bewildered while solving the mentioned ex 2.32.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> `[C++11: 5.19/3]:` A *literal constant expression* is a prvalue core constant expression of literal type, but not pointer type. An *integral constant expression* is a literal constant expression of integral or unscoped enumeration type. [..]

And:

> `[C++11: 3.9/10]:` **A type is a *literal type* if it is**:
>
> - **a scalar type**; or
> - a reference type; or
> - a class type (Clause 9) that has all of the following properties: [..]
> - an array of literal type.

At this point, I can't find a reason for that code to be non-compliant, so I suspect a GCC bug.

However it may be a deliberate bug given that the passage you quoted out of 4.10 is proposed to be changed ([active issue #903](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#903)) so that this would in fact be non-compliant code.

---

> The compilation succeeds if I `s/constexpr/const/` and compile with `-ansi` rather than `-std=c++11`.

The definition of *integral constant expression* explicitly allowed this case in C++03:

> `[C++03: 5.19/1]:` [..] An *integral constant-expression* can involve only literals (2.13), enumerators, **const variables** or static data members of integral or enumeration types initialized with constant expressions (8.5), non-type template parameters of integral or enumeration types, and `sizeof` expressions. [..]

Comment: Actually, your emphasis is wrong. You should have emphasized **literal constant expression**, and `int` is a literal type.

Comment: I think you are right that this is a GCC bug. However, that is only because this is actually a defect in the current standard. It is planned to remove this thing in the next iteration and only allow actual literal zeros as null pointer constants (i.e. none of that nonsense like `1-1` and so on)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Ah, interesting! Do you have an issue number perchance?

Comment: For reference, [this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#903) is the related DR.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Okay; how's that now?

Comment: weird how you say "you" to yourself.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Just playing the part!